# Allow optional parameter anywhere between subcommands

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to create a tool with sub-commands. I have a flag, for example `-j` which gives the output as JSON, and want the user to be able to pass it anywhere on the command line:

```
mytool courses list -j
mytool -j courses list
```

If I add the argument to my subparser, then I can only use the first version. If I add it to the main parser, then only the second version works.

I also tried using the `parents` argument, but that didn't work: If you pass the `-j` in the middle, then the last command doesn't see it and sets the variable to False.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', required=True)

common_args = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common_args.add_argument('-j', '--json', action='store_true', help='Output as JSON', default=None)

course_parser = subparser.add_parser('course', parents=[common_args])
course_subparser = course_parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcommand', required=True)

course_list_parser = course_subparser.add_parser('list', parents=[common_args])
```

Comment: The problem with the parents approach is that the subparser's default over rides the main's value..  Use a different `dest` at the two levels, and unify the values after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj This is really a bug of `argparse`. See my answer for a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tests I didn't find an easy way to do it.

However, this workaround allows you to do it

```py
import argparse


def add_common_args(parser, id):
    parser.add_argument(
        "-j",
        "--json",
        dest=f"json_{id}",
        action="store_true",
        help="Output as JSON",
        default=None,
    )


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)

course_parser = subparser.add_parser("course")
course_subparser = course_parser.add_subparsers(dest="subcommand", required=True)

course_list_parser = course_subparser.add_parser("list")

add_common_args(parser, 0)
add_common_args(course_parser, 1)
add_common_args(course_list_parser, 2)

args = parser.parse_args()
setattr(args, "json", any(getattr(args, f"json_{id}") for id in range(3)))
print(args)
```

The idea is to store the `--json` option of each parser into the argument `json_<id>` where `<id>` is an unique id for each parser.
Next, one the arguments of the command line are parsed, add the final `json` argument defined to `True` if any of the `json_<id>` is `True`.

This solution is not ideal but works.
Hope that's helping you.

Comment: Yes, the `dest` has to be different.  The code is explicitly written to give the subparser's default priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `common_args` a parent of the main parser as well as the subparsers so all parser instances share the `-j` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[common_args])
```

But then there's a bug in `argparse` where it creates a new `Namespace` for each parser instance instead of passing one along so the subparser has no idea of the fact that the main parser already got a `-j`, returning a new namespace with `json=None` and overriding the parent's value.

You can fix the bug by making `argparse.Namespace` always return the same namespace instead:

```
argparse.Namespace = lambda ns=argparse.Namespace(): ns
parser.parse_args()
```

or if for some reason you want the fix to apply only locally, you can use `unittest.mock.patch`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('argparse.Namespace', lambda ns=argparse.Namespace(): ns):
    parser.parse_args()
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/x5bjHr

Comment: There was an intentional patch, by the original author, to give the subparser a brand new namespace.  And the stated reason was to give the subparser default priority.  We can debate whether that was the best option, but it's not a bug.

Comment: I believe the OP's use case is common and reasonable enough to make a shared namespace an option at the very least. If you read the source code you'll find that it has all the logics for a subparser not to overwrite an existing key if it isn't a default value when provided with an existing namespace, but the logics are entirely wasted because the namespace from a previous parser is never propagated, which is why I classify it as a bug. My fix is at least simple enough a workaround before namespace propagation is made an option.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you're an active developer of `argparse`, if not the original author, so you certainly know the source code I'm talking about. I just want to add another common use case of a `--debug` option, as I am personally often frustrated at the inconsistency at which position the `--debug` option must be placed among different tools. It is far more intuitive to allow the users to place the option wherever they feel like as they type the command without altering the semantics than otherwise. And I thank you for your considerations and contribution. :-)

Comment: Your reassigned `Namespace` looks like it would work, though I'd have a hard time explaining its action to a novice user.  The original version that passed the main `namespace` to the subparser would handle this sort of `--debug` flag ok, since all levels would have the same default.  In an old bug/issue I suggested how the subparser action subclass could be replaced by an old style one.  A bigger problem with subparsers is that many users don't appreciate that it's a specialized positional argument, and that parsing gets passed to the subparser without much further main followup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approach this:

1. Make `-j` the global flag. That means it can appear anywhere
2. Parse `-j` first, then parse the rest

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-j",
    "--json",
    action="store_true",
    default=False,
    help="Output as JSON",
    default=None,
)
options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()

subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)
common_args = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)

course_parser = subparser.add_parser("course", parents=[common_args])
course_subparser = course_parser.add_subparsers(dest="subcommand", required=True)

course_list_parser = course_subparser.add_parser("list", parents=[common_args])

parser.parse_args(remainder, options)
print(options)
```

Here are some interactions:

```bash
$ mytool course list
Namespace(json=False, command='course', subcommand='list')

$ mytool course -j list
Namespace(json=True, command='course', subcommand='list')

$ mytool course list -j
Namespace(json=True, command='course', subcommand='list')

$ mytool -j course list
Namespace(json=True, command='course', subcommand='list')
```

Notes

1. I used `parse_known_args` for the first pass, which should parse the `-j` flag
2. `parse_known_args` returns `remainder`, which is the remainder of the command line, and `options`, which is the namespace with parsed information.
3. In the next pass, I use `parse_args`, but this time, passed in `remainder`, `options`